# Hive ParseExceptions - "cannot recognize input near ',' 'STRING' ','" and "cannot recognize input near ')' 'COMMENT' '"

Tags: sql-server, import, hive, sqoop, parse-error

When using Sqoop to import MSSQL table to Hive I get parse exception:

```
cannot recognize input near ',' 'STRING' ',' in column type
```

When I remove some columns from import I get another, but similar parse exception:

```
cannot recognize input near ')' 'COMMENT' ''Imported by sqoop on 2014/02/24 17:44:18'' in column type
```

Does it mean that some string field has ',' inside? Should I escape commas in strings? How to do this in Sqoop command line?

```
Logging initialized using configuration in jar:file:/usr/lib/hive/lib/hive-common-0.12.0.2.0.6.1-101.jar!/hive-log4j.properties
NoViableAltException(10@[])
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.type(HiveParser.java:27461)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.colType(HiveParser.java:27229)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.columnNameType(HiveParser.java:26935)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.columnNameTypeList(HiveParser.java:25211)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.createTableStatement(HiveParser.java:4264)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.ddlStatement(HiveParser.java:2016)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.execStatement(HiveParser.java:1298)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.statement(HiveParser.java:938)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.ParseDriver.parse(ParseDriver.java:190)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compile(Driver.java:424)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compile(Driver.java:342)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.runInternal(Driver.java:1000)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:911)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLocalCmd(CliDriver.java:259)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processCmd(CliDriver.java:216)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:413)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:348)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processReader(CliDriver.java:446)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processFile(CliDriver.java:456)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.executeDriver(CliDriver.java:737)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:675)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:614)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.apache.sqoop.hive.HiveImport.executeScript(HiveImport.java:329)
at org.apache.sqoop.hive.HiveImport.importTable(HiveImport.java:239)
at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.importTable(ImportTool.java:425)
at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.run(ImportTool.java:502)
at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:147)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:183)
at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:222)
at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:231)
at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:240)
```

FAILED: ParseException line 1:71 cannot recognize input near ',' 'STRING' ',' in column type

Comment: Please post the actual Sqoop command you use

Comment: @CarterShanklin Sqoop command that results in "cannot recognize input near ')' 'COMMENT' ''Imported by sqoop on ..." error message: ---------- sqoop import --connect "jdbc:sqlserver://mssql-serv:55316;database=DB_XXX" --username USER_YYY --password 123456 --query "select top (10) Имя, Модель, Телефон FROM Table_ZZZ where NULLIF(Имя, '') IS NOT NULL AND \$CONDITIONS" --target-dir /dwh/store -m 1 --null-string '\\N' --null-non-string '\\N' --hive-import --hive-table cars

Comment: @CarterShanklin As I now discovered this exception happens because Hive can not parse Cyrillic column names. The same exception happens when I simply try to create table with Cyrillic column names in Hive shell. Is there any way to make Hive understand Cyrillic column names?

Comment: I don't think so, but try surrounding the column names with backtick characters, e.g. select \`Имя\`. The other possibility is to try Sqoop import to HCatalog using the --hcatalog-database and --hcatalog-table options.